# Object oriented three address code generation

Tags: java, code-generation, compiler-optimization, compiler-construction

I'm working on a project related to compiler design. I need to generate three address code for a Java-based language and it implies the use of objects and scopes. I would like if you can help me generating TAC for the following example (or refer me to a tutorial):

```
class A {
    int x;
    String y;

    public A(int x, String y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
    }
}
```

---

```
import A;

class B {
    int f;
    A foo;

    public B() {
       this.foo = null;
       this.f = -1;
    }

    public boolean createFoo() {
       this.foo = new A(0, "TAC Example");
       return true;
    } 

    public static void main() {
       B bar = new B();
       A baz = new A(666, "TAC generation");
       bar.createFoo();
       bar.foo.y = "Hello World";
       if(bar.foo.x == 666)
           return;
       bar.foo.x = baz.x;           
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all you need to be aware of "object layout" or in another words how objects will look like in memory (RAM) in run-time. There is no standard for this, but most of compilers create object in similar manner. We will assume that execution will occur on x86 (32bit) machine so pointers are 4B or 32bits, while for 64bit (x64) machine, pointers are 8B. So object "A" will look like this: First 4Bytes of "A" object will be Pointer to Virtual Pointer Table. Next 4Bytes or offset 4 to 8 will store "int x". Offset 8 to 12 will store pointer to "String y". Virtual Pointer Table for class A can be empty OR Pointer on offset 0 in A object can be NULL - that depends on compiler. As for class "B" situation is similar. Offset 0 will store address of VPT (virtual pointer table), offset 4 "int f" and offset 8 pointer to "A foo". In VPT of B the "createFoo" address will be stored at offset 0, as it is only method in B class. Now lets make implementation:

```
_B.createFoo:
    BeginFunc 12    // stack frame size = 3 registers * sizeof( each_register )
    _t0 = 8         // size of A object
    PushParam _t0   // this is the memory ammount that we are asking
    _t1 = LCall _Alloc  // allocate memory
    PopParams 4     //  clear stack
    _t2 = A
    *(_t1) = _t2    // load VPT
    *(_t1 + 4) = 0  // initialize _A.x
    *(_t1 + 8) = "TAC Example"  // initialize _A.foo
    *(this + 8) = _t1
    Return 1
    EndFunc
```

Now let's implement main:

```
_B.main:
    BeginFunc 68    // 15 * 4 + 2 * 4 
    _t0 = 8         // size of B object
    PushParam _t0   // memory amount that we need
    _t1 = LCall _Alloc  // allocate memory
    PopParams 4     //  clear stack
    _t2 = B
    *(_t1) = _t2    // load VPT
    *(_t1 + 4) = 0  // initialize _B.foo
    *(_t1 + 8) = -1 // initialize _B.f
    bar = _t1
    _t3 = 8         // size of A object
    PushParam _t3   // this is the memory ammount that we are asking
    _t4 = LCall _Alloc  // allocate memory
    PopParams 4     //  clear stack
    _t5 = A
    *(_t4) = _t5    // load VPT
    *(_t4 + 4) = 666    // initialize _A.x
    *(_t4 + 8) = "TAC generation"   // initialize _A.foo
    baz = _t4
    _t6 = *(bar)    // address of _B.VPT
    _t7 = *(_t6)    // address of _B.createFoo
    PushParam bar   // this for createFoo
    ACall _t7       // call _B.createFoo
    PopParams 4     // clear stack
    _t8 = *(bar + 8)    // get _B.foo
    _t9 = *(_t8 + 8)    // get _B.foo.y
    *(_t9) = "Hello world"  // set _B.foo.y value
    _t10 = *(bar + 8)   // get _B.foo
    _t11 = *(_t10 + 4)  // get _B.foo.x
    _t12 = _t11 == 666  // test _B.foo.x equal to 666
    IfZ _t12 GoTo _L0   // if not equal continue to _L0
    Return
    _L0:
    _t13 = *(bar + 8)   // get _B.foo
    _t14 = _t13 + 4     // get address of _B.foo.x
    _t15 = *(baz + 4)   // get _A.x
    *(_t14) = _t15      // set _B.foo.x
    EndFunc
```

As you can see it is not too hard, but there is some work to do. Hope that this helps.

Comment: I was able to finish my project. Thanks anyway. Just a comment... Strings like `"TAC generation"` I allocated byte by byte in heap memory.

Comment: Good job. I am glad that I was helpful. Regards.

Comment: FYI, it is good StackOverflow etiquette to "accept" the best answer to your question so that the answer's author gets awarded reputation points for his efforts.

Comment: Any chance you could point to more resources on the theory of how to translate OO languages to TAC?